# Why can I move this vertex group but not rotate?

Tags: rigging, bones, vertex-groups

I'm new to rigging/skinning and following a tutorial to create an FPS reload animation. I have created, rigged and skinned the left arm but the right arm is giving me a lot of trouble. The hand part of the mesh has a (blue box)controller around it that I should be able to use to manipulate it however I can only grab and move the hand I can't rotate it. The left hand works fine. I've looked at them side by side, comparing any constraints/differences but I can't find anything that might be causing this. Rotation isn't locked either:

Here is the rest position:

[image: Rest position]

Here it is being grabbed and moved:
[image: Can be moved.]

Here is what happens when I rotate:
[image: Rotation]

I have deleted and reapplied the vertex groups but I don't think this is the problem.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Hello, can you please share your file?

Comment: Hi Moonboots, thanks for the reply. What's the best way to share the file? Apologies, new to this. Thanks.

Comment: Use https://blend-exchange.com/ or workupload and share the link

Comment: Thanks, I've added that to the post now!

Comment: Hand_L has a Copy Rotation constraint, the Hand_R has not, is it your problem here?

Comment: This was it.. Thanks so much! I guess I was looking at Hand_Ctrl_L and not seeing the constraint but I knew that would make sense, I appreciate the extra pair of eyes and the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hand_L* has a *Copy Rotation* constraint, the *Hand_R* has not, give it the same (with the right controller of course)